# Create "virtual switch" between servers with single network interface?

Tags: routing, opennebula

Is there a way to link two servers via internet as they would have been connected via simple network switch?

I have :

- Server A which only has single network interface eth0 with public IP
  AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA.
- Server B which only has single network interface eth0 with public IP
  BBB.BBB.BBB.BBB.

On each of those servers i have virtual machines (opennebula):

- server A has a virbr0 interface with 192.168.122.0/24 network
- server B has a virbr0 interface with 192.168.123.0/24 network

Virtual machines access internet via that virbr0 interface and everything works fine.
Server A and B also have a OpenVPN client installed, and OpenVPN server routes traffic to them form other vpn clients

Now what i would like to change, is link those two opennebula boxes (and later - more of them), and use only one 192.168.122.0/24 subnet (so that there would not be just single subnet for other vpn clients to access). Opennebula would ensure that there are no ip clashes, as it would allocate ip addresses.
If i would have a separate network card (eth1) via which those servers would be linked, i could just create a bridge, and it would work, but for now this not an option. Any way to accomplish this via some kind of software (network performance is not very important)

Comment: Open vSwitch was designed for exactly this sort of thing.

Comment: Thank you, Open vSwitch works - from A machine i can access B machine virtual machines, but the problem is i cannot access internet anymore from any of virtual machines